# Efficiently drawing graph of maximum degree $3$ with at most $o(n^2)$ crossings

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, graph-theory

Let $G$ be simple finite graph of order $n$ and maximum
degree $3$.

Can we efficiently draw $G$ with at most $o(n^2)$ crossings?

"Efficiently" means in time polynomial in $n$ or at worst
$\exp{o(n^2)}$.

In the [drawing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crossing_number_%28graph_theory%29) 
the edges are arbitrary curves.

---

According to [a paper](https://www.cis.upenn.edu/~sudipto/mypapers/embed.pdf)

> We compute a drawing on the plane of a bounded degree graph in which the sum of the numbers of vertices and crossings is $o(\log^3{n})$ times the optimal minimum sum

so bounding the crossing number will help.

If the crossing number of $G$ is too large the answer is negative.

Comment: Closely related question on MSE: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2147139/upper-bound-on-the-crossing-number-of-graph-of-maximum-degree-3